# Contextual Action Bar Text change for "DONE" button in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I have CAB menu in my application. I have a requirement to change the text on "DONE" button to "ADD". How can I do that?

I am able to see the design elements.But not for my requirement.

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable"></item>
<item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable"></item>
<item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable"></item>
<item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable"></item>
<item name="android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable"></item>
<item name="android:actionModeBackground"></item>
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle"></item>
```

Comment: IMHO, "Add" does not make sense when dismissing an action mode. An action mode, on its own, should *not* be changing the state of anything, just by being displayed. It simply brings up additional operations designed to be operated on something (e.g., checked-off items in a list).

Comment: I am adding some items to my list when the action bar is dismissed. So it will be good if the text is "ADD" instead of "DONE". Is it wrong in doing any operation while dismissing the action mode?

Comment: "I am adding some items to my list when the action bar is dismissed" -- IMHO, that is not a good idea. An action mode is nothing more than a better-looking context menu. Displaying a menu, and not selecting anything from it, should not be a destructive act. Similarly, displaying an action mode, and not doing anything with it, should not be a destructive act. Again, this is all my opinion.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for the suggestion. I will do the operation by adding another button on the CAB menu.

Comment: I suppose this question hasn't really been answered though - I have a similar case, where I need to change the "Done" text to "Cancel" - the user is cancelling the action, indicating that he does not want to change anything (pressing the back button has the same effect). Any pointers?

Comment: No luck for me till now!

Comment: Please look into this, it may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964939/remove-done-button-of-actionmode/17144854#17144854

Answer (score -3):

You define this in an xml files like other menus. Then reference that in the callback like so

```
private final class ModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = Activity.getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contexual_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        //Destroy something
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Well done you made an custom CAB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

Make sure you start the actionMode like this

```
startActionMode(new ModeCallback());
```

Comment: I have a working code for Action mode listener. I am not asking for that. I just want to change the text("DONE") nearer to the tick mark in the left side of CAB menu.

Comment: You should edit your question you wrote "I have a requirement to change the text on "DONE" button to "ADD""

Comment: I quoted him, what is the question?